# Add calendar to Quartz job by configuration

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I want to block some of my Quartz jobs to run on holidays, on [the official Quartz page about triggers](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-triggers.html%20%22official%20Quartz%20page%20about%20triggers%20and%20calendars%22.), we can read:

> Quartz.NET Calendar objects implementing ICalendar interface can be associated with triggers at the time the trigger is stored in the scheduler. Calendars are useful for excluding blocks of time from the the trigger’s firing schedule. For instance, you could create a trigger that fires a job every weekday at 9:30 am, but then add a Calendar that excludes all of the business’s holidays.

My triggers are defined in config files, e.g.:

```
<trigger>
  <simple>
    <name>a trigger</name>
    <group>a trigger group</group>
    <description>a trigger description</description>
    <job-name>AJobName</job-name>
    <job-group>a job group</job-group>
    <job-data-map>
      <entry>
        <key>param1</key>
        <value>param1value</value>
      </entry>
    </job-data-map>
    <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
    <repeat-interval>300000</repeat-interval>
  </simple>
</trigger>
```

Can I, without altering the C# code, block triggers from firing on dates in my holiday calendar?
If not, can I at least keep the trigger definition in the config and add the calendar in code and assign it to the specific trigger?

So, this programmatic solution is not what I am looking for: [programmatically create trigger and assign calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999413/setting-weekend-or-holiday-strategy-while-scheduling-quartz-scheduler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger XML configuration allows you to configure a calendar by name:

```
<trigger>
  <simple>
    <calendar-name>myHolidayCalendar<calendar-name>
  </simple>
</trigger>
```

For this to work the holiday calendar must be registered in the scheduler:

```
var calendar = new HolidayCalendar();
calendar.addExcludedDate(DateTime.Today);
scheduler.addCalendar("myHolidayCalendar", calendar, false);
```

Comment: So, I still have to add the calendar programmatically to the scheduler, right? Or can I implement some trigger initialisation code -> IF calendar-name present THEN add to scheduler?

Comment: That is correct, the calendar still needs to be added to the scheduler programmatically; I'll include this in my answer

Comment: how it works with dynamic dates (for example Easter)?

Comment: @Ans you would need to exclude each date (for every year) separately. I believe there are algo's for christian holidays so you could just calculate the dates for say the next 100 years?